# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect, list to checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, tomcat7

i getting an error when submitting a form:
ERROR 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

I am using Hibernate 4, Spring 3 and JSP pages in a Tomcat 7 with servlet 3.0

I got an Order class that extends BaseEntity ( BaseEntity got the uuid member that is auto generated ):

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "orders")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "orders_additional_options", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "orders_uuid", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "additionalOptions_uuid", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    protected Set<AdditionalOption> selectedAdditionalOptions = new HashSet<AdditionalOption>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Order() {
        super("");
    }


    /**
     * @return the selectedAdditionalOptions
     */
    public Set<AdditionalOption> getSelectedAdditionalOptions() {
        return selectedAdditionalOptions;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedAdditionalOptions the selectedAdditionalOptions to set
     */
    public void setSelectedAdditionalOptions(
            Set<AdditionalOption> selectedAdditionalOptions) {
        this.selectedAdditionalOptions = selectedAdditionalOptions;
    }



}
```

In Order I got a list of AdditionalOption, AdditionalOption class look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "additional_options")
public class AdditionalOption extends BaseEntity {

    @Column (nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "selectedAdditionalOptions")
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AdditionalOption()
    {
        super("");
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I create a JSP page with a form for new Order in the form i want the user to select with checkboxes from a list of additional options.

so the code looks like this: ( uuid comes from BaseEntity, availableAdditionalOptions comes from a select all query on the AdditionalOptions table )

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="order" action="/menuapp/order/create" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Additional Options:</td>
        <td><form:checkboxes items="${availableAdditionalOptions}" path="selectedAdditionalOptions" itemLabel="name" itemValue="uuid"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input value="Order" type="submit">
    </tr>
  </table>
</form:form>
```

so the page is shown well but when I click on the submit button i get the error:
ERROR 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

the controller that handles the submit looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute Order order) {
        orderService.saveOrUpdate(order);
            model.addAttribute("saved", "success");
            return "order";
        }
```

but it never gets there...

I checked with wireshark what is send in the HTML POST request and got this:

```
 selectedAdditionalOptions=ae396f42-843c-454d-a573-85e71c36709d&selectedAdditionalOptions=962e0766-5e56-4490-bc50-d4f41272c77e&_selectedAdditionalOptions=on
```

I found the following error in my log4j file:

```
013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/menuapp/order/create]
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /order/create
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:227 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.openu.menuapp.controller.OrderController.save(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.openu.menuapp.entity.Order)]
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'orderController'
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG BeanUtils:443 - No property editor [com.openu.menuapp.entity.AdditionalOptionEditor] found for type com.openu.menuapp.entity.AdditionalOption according to 'Editor' suffix convention
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.openu.menuapp.controller.OrderController.save(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.openu.menuapp.entity.Order)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'order' on field 'selectedAdditionalOptions': rejected value [962e0766-5e56-4490-bc50-d4f41272c77e]; codes [typeMismatch.order.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [order.selectedAdditionalOptions,selectedAdditionalOptions]; arguments []; default message [selectedAdditionalOptions]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.openu.menuapp.entity.AdditionalOption] for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.openu.menuapp.controller.OrderController.save(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.openu.menuapp.entity.Order)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'order' on field 'selectedAdditionalOptions': rejected value [962e0766-5e56-4490-bc50-d4f41272c77e]; codes [typeMismatch.order.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [order.selectedAdditionalOptions,selectedAdditionalOptions]; arguments []; default message [selectedAdditionalOptions]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.openu.menuapp.entity.AdditionalOption] for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.openu.menuapp.controller.OrderController.save(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.openu.menuapp.entity.Order)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'order' on field 'selectedAdditionalOptions': rejected value [962e0766-5e56-4490-bc50-d4f41272c77e]; codes [typeMismatch.order.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.selectedAdditionalOptions,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [order.selectedAdditionalOptions,selectedAdditionalOptions]; arguments []; default message [selectedAdditionalOptions]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.openu.menuapp.entity.AdditionalOption] for property 'selectedAdditionalOptions[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2013-11-04 20:46:56 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
```

**I cant answer to my own questions so I write the answer here:**

Ok, the problem was the convertor from Uuid as String to AdditionalOption object

so i add the following binding to my controller:

```
@Autowired
private AdditionalOptionConvertor additionalOptionConvertor;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(AdditionalOption.class, additionalOptionConvertor);
}
```

When AdditionalOptionConvertor is a Service that gets Autowired and looks like this:

```
@Service("additionalOptionConvertor")
public class AdditionalOptionConvertor extends BaseConvertor<AdditionalOption>
{
    @Autowired
    protected AdditionalOptionService service;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        baseService = service;
        super.setAsText(text);
    }

}
```

I also add BaseConvertor class because all my objects share the Uuid member and all services got the findByUuid that return a BaseEntity object
So the BaseConvertor looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseConvertor<T extends BaseEntity> extends PropertyEditorSupport
{

    protected BaseEntityService baseService;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        T value =  baseService.findByUUID(text);
        setValue(value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String getAsText()
    {
        T d = (T) getValue();
        return d != null ? String.valueOf(d.getUuid()) : "";
    }   
}
```

for more information about the PropertyEditorSupport go to:
[Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html)

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Not enough information from the Server perspective to know if you are sending a correct POST since that is what HTTP 400 means... BAD REQUEST.. I'll suggest sending your request you got from wireshark directly through an HTTP tester to see your syntax is correct

Comment: hi, i add the server log.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was the convertor from Uuid as String to AdditionalOption object

so i add the following binding to my controller:

```
@Autowired
private AdditionalOptionConvertor additionalOptionConvertor;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(AdditionalOption.class, additionalOptionConvertor);
}
```

When AdditionalOptionConvertor is a Service that gets Autowired and looks like this:

```
@Service("additionalOptionConvertor")
public class AdditionalOptionConvertor extends BaseConvertor<AdditionalOption>
{
    @Autowired
    protected AdditionalOptionService service;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        baseService = service;
        super.setAsText(text);
    }

}
```

I also add BaseConvertor class because all my objects share the Uuid member and all services got the findByUuid that return a BaseEntity object
So the BaseConvertor looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseConvertor<T extends BaseEntity> extends PropertyEditorSupport
{

    protected BaseEntityService baseService;

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        T value =  baseService.findByUUID(text);
        setValue(value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String getAsText()
    {
        T d = (T) getValue();
        return d != null ? String.valueOf(d.getUuid()) : "";
    }   
}
```

for more information about the PropertyEditorSupport go to:
[Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html)

Thanks for the helpers